# UISplitView weird background behind navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I've got an application with the following view architecture:

```
UITabBarController > UISplitViewController > UINavigationController > UIViewController
                                         \ 
                                           > UINavigationController > UIViewController
```

Whenever I push a view controller embedded in a navigation controller as the detail view, I see a weird off-colour view appear behind the main navigation bar. This happens when my app is in both light and dark mode, as can be seen in the screenshots below.

I've recreated the same view architecture in a test app, and I'm not seeing the off-colour view appear, so I'm not sure what's causing it.

Here's some of the code I'm using to create the light/dark mode:

```
extension UINavigationBar: RMDThemeable {

    func render(for theme: RMDTheme) {
        switch theme {
        case .light:
            barStyle = .default
        case .dark:
            barStyle = .black
        }
    }
}

class RMDCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    func render(for theme: RMDTheme) {
        switch theme {
        case .light:
            collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.baseBackgroundLight
        case .dark:
            collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.baseBackgroundDark
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the screenshots of the weird colour:

[image: No weird off-colour view]
[image: Weird off-colour view]
[image: Weird off-colour view in white]

Here's the view debugger:

[image: Screenshot with prominent grey bar]
[image: View debugger of prominent grey bar]

Comment: that could be UIWindow. try changing background color for UIWindow

Comment: I thought it might be the window, so I tried setting its background colour as well, but it had no effect. The off-colour view also only appears when the detail view controller is a `UINavigationController`. If I push a regular view controller, it looks fine.

Comment: That's strange. I am guessing you might have already tried view debugger?

Comment: Yeah. In both the test app and my real app, there's a light grey bar that appears behind both navigation bars. On the test app (where everything is normal), the base view of the visual effect view (in the left navigation bar) is normally coloured. In my app, it appears as a similar colour to that grey bar. It's like it was using the grey bar when rendering, even though it's buried beneath the left view controller. I'll add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not checked for the `translucent` property of `UINavigationController`, either set the value to `false` or create custom navigation bars with your desired colour.

To set the `translucent` property you can go to storyboard and select the Navigation controller's attribute inspector, on top there will be a check box marking `translucent` uncheck it or it can be done in the code like

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

> Get instance of your navigation controller and set it to false.

Comment: I want the bars to be translucent, so I've kept the property to `true`. I have a sample application that also has the property set to `true`, and everything works fine: https://github.com/mpdifran/SplitViewTest

Comment: Hey there i went thorough it and could you please see for the colours set for navigation bar tint colour in either storyboard or the code cause i tried some colours and it turned out to be like this https://ibb.co/hvx1Xy, the colours i have added are dark grey for the master navigation controller nav bar and Black for the detail.

Comment: I'm not setting any colours for the navigation bar in my main project, I'm only using the light and dark blurred bar. Also, if you take a close look at the screenshot I posted, you can see that the grey bar is behind the translucent navigation bar, since the edges of the bar are not fully grey. In your screenshot, the navigation bar is a solid grey rectangle.